# Calculation of cubic root in Python (why the result is missing the 64?)

Tags: python-3.x

```
minval = 2
maxval = 130
cube_no = []
for d in range(minval, maxval+1, 1):
   x = d**(1/3)
   if x.is_integer(): 
   cube_no.append(d)
```

Output:
cube_no = [8, 27, 125]

Why is 64 not in the output?

How to calculate the exact cubic root value of a cubic integer number?

Comment: 1/3 is not representable exactly as a float, so `1/3` generates a floating point approximation and thus even if the cube root should be an integer you're not guaranteed that the `1/3` power will be. It will be very close however.

Comment: Agree. In general I'd encourage you to check your output with some print statements (the oldest form of debugging) or in a modern IDE set a breakpoint and inspect the local values. You'll find that 64**(1/3) Is 3.9999999999999996 and so not an integer. Hence, it fails your IF test.

Comment: Got it, so what is a proper way to calculate cubic root in python?

Comment: Have you checked out my answer? What about accepting/upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments and in past duplicates of same kind of question the reason why 64 isn't in the output is a floating point representation related issue ( "Got it, so what is a proper way to calculate cubic root in python?" )

You can overcome the floating point representation issue for `**(1/3)` by replacing cubic root with exponentiation to power of 3 :

```
minval = 2
maxval = 130
cube_no = []
for x in range(
        int(minval**(1/3)-0.1), 
        int(maxval**(1/3)+0.1)+1): 
    d = x**3
    if minval <= d <= maxval: 
        cube_no.append(d)
print(cube_no) # gives: [8, 27, 64, 125]
```

Notice that the code above performs much less calculations saving computation time.

By the way: in Python 3.11 the math module ( `import math` ) provides a `math.cbrt()` cubic root function: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/math.html#math.cbrt

In Python 3.x up to 3.10 you can use the `numpy` modules `cbrt()` to get the exact floating point value of cubic root for 64:

```
import numpy as np
d = 64
x = np.cbrt(d)
print(x) # gives 4.0
```